# Variable passed to SQL statement returns nothing, no errors though

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, vb6, vb4android

I'm passing a variable to an SQL query.

```
Dim accept As String
accept = Cursor1.GetString("accepted_id")
    Msgbox(accept, "")  
    Cursor1 = SQL1.ExecQuery("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE accepted_id =" & " 'accept' " )
```

There's more code but that should be enough. There are no errors and the msgbox shows the correct answer. it all looks good but it's not retrieving any results.

If I hardcode the answer instead of the variable it works, such as,

```
 Dim accept As String
    accept = Cursor1.GetString("accepted_id")
        Msgbox(accept, "")  
        Cursor1 = SQL1.ExecQuery("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE accepted_id =" & " 'CD6028' " )
```

The msgbox shows CD6028.

The results show show in a listview but nothing.

Comment: You needed to `msgbox` the sql query to see your error. Not the variable though a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are passing litteral string `accept` to the variable instead of variable `accept` itself.

Replace this :

```
Cursor1 = SQL1.ExecQuery("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE accepted_id =" & " 'accept' " )
```

With :

```
Cursor1 = SQL1.ExecQuery("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE accepted_id = '" & accept & "'")
```